# Is there a way of connecting manifolds together in a higher dimension?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

This question might be very naive since I haven't taken much topology or differential geometry yet; so please make the answer more conceptual than mathematical. We can think of a two dimensional sheet as joining an infinite number of one dimensional lines along a second dimension that doesn't exist for the lines. This also works if the surface is curved, only now, the lines are one dimensional curves.

So, in a sense, spaces can be joined together along a higher dimension if the lower dimensional spaces change slowly enough as we move along the higher dimension - or else we would not have a smooth surface at the end. If what I meant is not clear, the image below might explain it better:

[image]

[image]

In a sense, what I mean by the curves changing too fast is that after combining them, the resulting surface might not be continuous or differentiable (but I suppose I can only say this if the surface can be embedded in a euclidean space).

So my question is this: given an infinite set of manifolds (reasonably smooth or continuous and not necessarily reimannian) of dimension "n", is there a way to connect them like above in a higher dimension to give us a n+1 dimensional manifold?

If so, what conditions do the manifolds need to satisfy (conceptually)? If this question is too mathematical to answer conceptually, please list a few sources or let me know what this is called so that I can read about this myself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question and there are a couple of different ways to make it precise, all of which lead to quite interesting mathematics. One is to ignore everything happening in the "middle" and focus on the "ends"; that is, we will settle for connecting two manifolds, forget about infinitely many for now. Then what you are talking about is known as a **[cobordism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism)** between two manifolds $M, N$, meaning a manifold in one higher dimension whose boundary is $M \sqcup N$. If a cobordism exists between $M, N$ they are said to be *cobordant*. As a simple example, the [pair of pants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_pants_(mathematics)) is a cobordism between a circle $S^1$ and two circles $S^1 \sqcup S^1$:

[image]

If you slice up a pair of pants and think of it as a "movie" going forward in time you'll note that in the middle you get a wedge of two circles, which is not a manifold. This sort of thing is investigated in **[Morse theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory)**, which is a whole fascinating topic in itself and about which I will say nothing more.

As a general question we can ask:

> **Question:** When are two $n$-manifolds $M, N$ cobordant?

You might think that this is a hard and deep problem in manifold topology. Remarkably, for [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold) $n$-manifolds this question has a more-or-less *complete answer* due to Thom. Associated to any such $n$-manifold is a bunch of numbers called the [Stiefel-Whitney numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class), which take values $\bmod 2$, and Thom showed:

> **Theorem (Thom):** Two closed $n$-manifolds $M, N$ are cobordant iff their Stiefel-Whitney numbers are the same.

The simplest Stiefel-Whitney number to explain is called $w_n$, and it's given by the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) $\bmod 2$. It's a nice exercise to show that this is a *cobordism invariant*, meaning that if $M$ and $N$ are cobordant then $\chi(M) \equiv \chi(N) \bmod 2$.

> **Corollary:** A closed manifold with odd Euler characteristic is not cobordant to a closed manifold with even Euler characteristic.

For example, the [real projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) $\mathbb{RP}^2$ has Euler characteristic $1$ and so is not cobordant to the torus $T^2$ (Euler characteristic $0$) or the $2$-sphere $S^2$ (Euler characteristic $2$). However, the torus and the $2$-sphere are cobordant (exercise), and in fact every pair of closed orientable surfaces is cobordant (exercise). This is a very special case of Thom's theorem (which can be proven much more easily than what Thom did), since it turns out that for such surfaces both of the Stiefel-Whitney numbers (which are called $w_1^2$ and $w_2$) vanish.

There's a whole lot more to say here about [cobordism rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism_ring) and so forth but this is a good place to stop for now, I think.